# Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state

Tags: sql, sql-server, dml

I try to execute a update query in SQL Server 2016 (v13.0.5026.0) and get these error messages:

> Msg 596, Level 21, State 1, Line 0
>   Cannot continue the execution because the session is in the kill state.
>
> Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
>   A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

Checked for corrupted index or anything

```
DBCC CheckDB (DBNAME) WITH NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS
```

--Returns no error

As Microsoft suggested update with the below link:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4163478/fix-access-violation-when-incremental-statistics-automatically-updated

I tried an update to Cummulative Update(CU6) and changed to 13.0.5292.0
It says CU1 update has to fix it but doesn't solve the issue.

The query is:

```
UPDATE tableName 
SET fieldName1 = 'a long query with some html tags and all it has 3600 chars' 
WHERE fieldName2 = 12345
```

It doesn't have any special characters that SQL can't handle.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Do you have any automated processes running on this server? Say, something that automatically might kill long-running queries? The article you linked mentions a problem with updating statistics. Perhaps a resolution may be to use an account with more access. Maybe test with a sysadmin account and see if you still get the error?

Comment: Thanks Jacob, but didn't help even with the more access rights.

Comment: Do you  AlwaysOn or Mirroring on the underlying database enabled? Is this issue reproducable every time when you run that update?

Comment: No, I dont have the AlwaysOn feature enabled for the SQL Server. And yes the issue is reproducable every time for this table but if I take the same string and try the update on a different table, it works perfectly. Can this be because of the full text search or anything else?